# Simple Git Bash .sh Script on windows to change directory does not work. Basic change directory in .sh script

Tags: windows, bash, git, sh, cd

Trying to make a script to automate activating a virtual environment for my django project.
Here is my script which I save as 'activatevirt.sh'.  The first couple lines work, but then
when it gets to the lines to change directory it doesn't change the directory.  Could someone please give me the exact code to implement this?  I've read a few answers on here that were
confusing for me and were not helpful.  If someone could simply give me the exact code which
would give me a script which would change the directory in git bash for windows that would
excellent!  Thanks.

'''

```
#!/bin/bash

python -m venv virt
echo testing and this line works too.
cd virt #this line doesn't work!
cd scripts # this line doesn't work either!
source activate # this line might work if it were in the right directory... not sure yet!
whoami
```

'''

Comment: "doesn't work" is really unhelpful. Error message?

Comment: i got it to work.  for whatever reason, when running commands at the command line in bit bash, the command 'cd c:' works to change directory to the c: directory, however it does not work when implemented from within a .sh script file.  I was able to by brute force figure out that instead writing the command in the script file in this syntax instead does work. "cd /c/".  This does in fact allow the script file to change the directory as one would expect.  why it does not allow the standard usage of cd c: is a mystery to me, most likely a programming oversight in bit bash.

Answer (score 1):

Both `cd virt` and `cd scripts` use *relative path* definition, which can fail in case of not expected "current" directory

Detect full absolute path to `/some/path/to/virt/scripts` and **use it!!!**

Comment: So how exactly would I do that... I'm sorry if I'm asking too much or if it seems like I'm asking for you to do absolutely everything but I'm a total newb when it comes to git bash in general, let alone script writing for it..

Comment: I tried this and got the following output:

$ sh activatevirt.sh
testing and this line works too.
activatevirt.sh: line 5: source: activate: file not found

`code`
#!/bin/bash
python -m venv virt
echo testing and this line works too.
cd c:/simpleblog/virt/scripts
source activate
whoami
`code`

I'm sorry i'm also new to stack overflow and don;t know how to format my replys

Comment: how would i 'detect full absolute path and use it??? can you give me a more direct example of exactly how this would be done? again sorry if im asking you to dumb something down to the point where you are astounded that I really don't understand what you're implying i am to do here.  I thank you for your time and help.